# flask-restless validation_exceptions not working for few column in flask-sqlalchemy models

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I am using Flask-Restless for creating /api/v1/candidate. There I have used `validation_exceptions=[MyValidationError]`

```
# ... code snippet from my models.py ....

class MyValidationError(Exception):
    pass

def validate_required_field(method):
    def wrapper(self, key, string):
        if not string:
            exception = MyValidationError()
            exception.errors = {key: 'must not be empty'}
            raise exception
        return method(self, key, string)
    return wrapper

class Candidate(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'candidate'

    # ... snip ...
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)  
    phone = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # ... snip ...

    @orm.validates('first_name')
    @validate_required_field
    def validate_first_name(self, key, string):
        return string

    @orm.validates('phone')
    @validate_required_field
    def validate_first_name(self, key, string):
        return string
```

Note: I have written `validate_required_field` decorator to avoid code repetition.

When I POST data to `/api/v1/candidate` with empty **phone** column, it validates it right and gives me error

```
{
    "validation_errors": {
        "phone": "must not be empty"
    }
}
```

But when I pass empty **first_name** column, same thing does not happen :(

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You duplicated your function `validate_first_name` for both `phone` and `first_name` fields.